# Unable to fetch data in Elequent Polymorphic Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I was building a commenting system using the [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), it seems like everything works without any issue.
[image]

Here is my Posts Model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'pid';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'p_author_id');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }

}
```

Here is my Comment Model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Posts', 'pid');
    }

}
```

Now the problem is,

```
$pin = Posts::find($pin_id);
```

is not returning any comments associated with the post! Note that it has the author entity but not the comments.

```
print_r($pin->toArray());
```

would only return the following array,

```
Array
(
    [pid] => 17
    [p_title] => Hello World?
    [p_content] => How are you earth?
    [p_author_id] => 4
    [p_created_at] => 2016-09-15 17:18:16
    [p_updated_at] => 2016-09-15 17:18:16
    [comments_count] => 0
    [votes] => 0
    [author] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Human
            [email] => human@mail.com
            [created_at] => 2016-09-15 17:18:00
            [updated_at] => 2016-09-15 17:20:05
        )

)
```

why the **comments** entity is missing here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) like following:

```
$pin = Posts::with('comments')->find($pin_id);
```

And use **App\Posts** instead of **Posts** in your `commentable_type` column in database. That's because: (Quoting from the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations))

> The commentable_type column is how the ORM determines which "type" of owning model to return when accessing the commentable relation.

Also please follow the [naming convention for models](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It still returns a null.
`print_r($pin->replies->toArray()) outputs empty array`

Comment: try dd($pin) and check if the 'comments' attribute is showing?

Comment: I did everything again from scratch and renamed the comments entity to replies in my project though everything remains same. with `dd($pin)` it shows that the "replies" a.k.a "comments" attribute is empty [http://i.imgur.com/K8iMJkT.png](http://i.imgur.com/K8iMJkT.png)

Comment: Use **App\Posts** instead of **Posts** in your *commentable_type* column value and then check again.

Comment: I've updated the answer, if anyone need it later. And thanks for the upvote and making it accepted. :)